# Is it unfriendly or unwelcoming to point out that the OP is being rude or unreasonable?

Tags: discussion, comments, unfriendly-or-unkind

There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55168338/compare-object-to-null-pointer-in-cpp-not-working) (it didn't last long) to which several people have asked for MCVE, to which the OP (new contributor) with increasing hostility and exclamation points kept replying that their example is enough. Despite the fact that people they were "yelling" at kept politely explaining why the example isn't complete and why they need to provide a complete one, it didn't seem completely right to me, because not only the OP didn't understand the value of MCVE but it seemed that they also weren't aware that their behavior was inappropriate.

So my question is whether it is rude or unwelcoming to point out that "yelling" at people that are trying to help them for free isn't going to help them to get an answer? (I expect that "for free" part is probably too snarky)

And a more general question: should we ever use comments to point out inappropriate behavior in order to educate the contributor or should we just stick to flags and votes?

My rationale **for** doing that is that downvotes are never obvious and "close" reasons are usually too generic to help the contributor to understand what they have done wrong.

Comment: Do you expect a positive outcome to telling someone they are not behaving correctly?

Comment: @fbueckert, realistically, I don't expect them to be happy about it but at least they'll have an explanation. A lot of people go to Meta trying to figure out downvotes and VTCs they receive and I think a lot more don't even bother.

Comment: So, if there isn't a positive outcome...why are you doing it?  Downvotes don't need comments by design, and this is one of the reasons.  Downvote, flag as appropriate, and move on.

Comment: @fbueckert, the positive outcome *might* be that it would educate the newcomer about community's standards versus giving a perception "this community is deliberately unhelpful".

Comment: That perception happens anyways, as questions are subjected to curation.  Telling someone their question is not up to our standards isn't going to elict a good response, no matter how gentle you are about it.  New users get a ton of content presented before they can ask their first question, and they have to confirm that they've read it before they can continue.  Almost none of them actually do.  We can only be so helpful.  Once you post, your post is subject to curation.  We can't help those that refuse to help themselves.

Comment: Alternatively, you could point them to the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) neutrally and read about "Our Expectations", but be very careful because we don't want to use CoC as a "shield" instead.

Answer (score 14):

If a user's immediate action is to become hostile, telling them to calm down typically doesn't work. The best thing you can do is explain how they can improve their question (optional), and flag their comments appropriately. Engaging with the hostility just creates comment noise and wastes your time at the end game.

Answer (score 7):

I want to remark to this specific statement:

> My rationale **for** doing that is that downvotes are never obvious and "close" reasons are usually too generic to help the contributor to understand what they have done wrong.

...except it wasn't.  The close reason was:

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Your comment, and others like it, were in effect similar to the close reason, so your rationale for commentating in this fashion is moot.  The message to the OP is clear when the question is closed; if there's not enough detail in their question, they cannot actually get a reasonable answer.

Now, is it *unwelcoming*?  I wouldn't venture quite that far.  ***One*** of these comments in good faith isn't *so* bad; five or six can turn into noise pretty quickly (which is ripe for removal) as the OP grows more and more exasperated trying to appease the crowd.

Remember: the whole *point* of MCVE is to ensure that the user has enough details in the question that it can be answered, including relevant code, exceptions, and input.  This is all in the name of context; if you can actually answer the question with the provided context, then cries of MCVE quickly turn into noise, too.

Comment: Sorry, I have no way of knowing why it was closed because it's deleted. In this case I think it might be even worse because the inappropriate behavior isn't addressed at all and the contributor might continue to behave this way in the future.

Comment: That's fair @r3musn0x; the OP deleted it two minutes after it was closed.  I have 10K+ rep so I can see the deleted post.

Comment: Also @r3musn0x - if they do continue, they'll just get question banned.  That would address the behavior by putting a hard stop to it.